# Drawbacks of K-Medoid (PAM) Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I have researched that K-medoid Algorithm (PAM) is a parition-based clustering algorithm and a variant of K-means algorithm. It has solved the problems of K-means like producing empty clusters and the sensitivity to outliers/noise.

However, the time complexity of K-medoid is O(n^2), unlike K-means (Lloyd's Algorithm) which has a time complexity of O(n). I would like to ask if there are other drawbacks of K-medoid algorithm aside from its time complexity.

Comment: Actually the worst-case runtime of k-means is much worse than O(n); and probably not that different from k-medoids. Also you need to be  *much* more precise. You are probaly talking about Lloyds algorithm and PAM. k-means is the *problem*, not the way of solving it; same for k-medoids.

Comment: Yup, The k-means i'm talking here is lloyd's algorithm and the k-medoids is Paritioning around medoids.

Comment: The question is rather for stats.stackexchange.com .

Comment: "the time complexity of K-medoid is O(n^2), unlike K-means (Lloyd's Algorithm) which has a time complexity of O(n)." - do you mean that the time complexity of each iteration is O(n^2) and O(n) ?  Because the time complexity of K-means is not O(n), not even close.

Comment: Oh is it really? Then what is the complexity of K-means, and do you know other drawbacks of PAM (K-medoid)?

Comment: See relevant literature for the worst case of Lloyds, and whether this also applies to PAM. I'd guess it also applies (but night not be proven yet), and it's something really bad like 2^O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main disadvantage of K-Medoid algorithms (either PAM, CLARA or CLARANS) is that they are not suitable for clustering non-spherical (arbitrary shaped) groups of objects. 
This is because they rely on minimizing the distances between the non-medoid objects and the medoid (the cluster center) - briefly, they use compactness as clustering criteria instead of connectivity.

Another disadvantage of PAM is that it may obtain different results for different runs on the same dataset because the first *k* medoids are chosen randomly.

In addition to the aforementioned disadvantages, you must also specify the value for *k* (the number of clusters) in advance.

Comment: I know the question is an year old and you may not need this answer anymore, but I posted it anyway in case there is somebody else needing it.