# Selection of initial medoids in PAM algorith

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-partitioning

I have read a couple of different articles on how PAM selects the initial medoids but I am getting conflicting views.

Some propose that the k first medoids are selected randomly, while others suggest that the algorithm selects initially the k representative medoids in the dataset (not clarifying how that "representativeness" happens though). Below I have listed these resources:

[Medoid calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394744/medoid-calculation)

[Drawbacks of K-Medoid (PAM) Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514123/drawbacks-of-k-medoid-pam-algorithm)

https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~ec/files_1112/week_06_Clustering_part_II.pdf

https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/k-medoids-in-r-algorithm-and-practical-examples/

1) My question would be if someone could explain in more detail how the algorithm selects the initial k medoids as from what I understand different initial selection can lead to different results.

2) Also is that one of the reasons of using CLARA (apart from minimizing computing time and RAM storage problem) - that is to find medoids through resampling that are the "optimal" options?

I am using R as a parenthesis, with the function pam(). Open to other functions in other libraries if there is a better alternative I am not aware of.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? The wikipedia papers are behind a paywall.

Answer (score 2):

Read the *original* sources.

There is a lot of nonsense written later, unfortunately.

PAM consists of two algorithms:

1. BUILD to choose the initial medoids (*not* randomly)
2. SWAP to make the best improvements (*not* k-means style)

The k-means style algorithm works *much* worse than PAM. Any description of PAM that doesn't mention these two parts is inaccurate (and there are quite some of these...)

The R package seems to use the real PAM algorithm:

> By default, when medoids are not specified, the algorithm first looks for a good initial set of medoids (this is called the **build** phase). Then it finds a local minimum for the objective function, that is, a solution such that there is no single switch of an observation with a medoid that will decrease the objective (this is called the **swap** phase)

CLARA clearly will find worse solutions than PAM, as it runs PAM on a sample, and I'd the optimum medoids are not in the sample, then they cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, could you give me a couple of references on the original sources?

Comment: They should be linked in Wikipedia.